# Encrypt the file for security

Tags: security, encryption, zip, tar, bzip

Actually I have a file . I am working in linux environment. 
I need to encrypt that file for secure purpose with giving the some password. 
The operation could be like zip ,  tar any compression. When I extract the file It should ask 
me password , only then it should get extracted

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gpg --symmetric` and `gpg --decrypt` should do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Simple, use openssl.

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in plain.txt -out myultrasecretfile.enc
```

If you want to compress before, that is your choice.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [GPG](http://www.gnupg.org/).

Or, you can use any zip library that supports AES...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `vi -x filename` ?  It is not exactly full-featured encryption, but it might do what you want.

Comment: Yea , I used but it corrupts data's when we are giving the wrong password

Comment: Yes, it does, but only if you save it when you get the "corrupt" data.  I believe that vi is not a good choice for you, given that you accepted gpg above.  But it was the simplest, and that was my intent.

Answer (score 0):

i like `aespipe` as you can use it completely non-interactively from command line or scripts, and it will work with any stream of data.